# Spyder can't import local module while command line runs fine

Tags: python, python-import, spyder

I'm writing scripts with Spyder (Anaconda 2021.05 which has python 3.8.8, IPython 7.22.0, spyder 4.2.5, **Windows**) but the script needs to be run under Anaconda command line, so I want to find a way of `import` that works in both setup.

My folders look like this

```
project/processes/main.py
project/utils/date.py
```

and in `main.py`, I add my module into `sys.path`

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
print(sys.path)

import utils.date
```

This runs fine under command line, but under spyder it says

```
*** ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.date'; 'utils' is not a package
```

The print of `sys.path` is different under command line and under spyder (as expected), but they both include the `project` folder. How could I make spyder/ipython see my local module?

Comment: maybe you should find path to `python` used in anaconda line and later set this path in Spider to run code with the same python

Comment: maybe first check `print( os.getcwd() )` to see in which folder it runs it. Maybe you should add directy `os.getcwd()` without `dirname()`. OR maybe first try manually add this folder `sys.path.append("/full/path/to/project")`

Comment: what version of python do you use in Spyder? Maybe it use older version which doesn't know how to work with new packages. maybe it will need to add file `__init__.py` inside folder `utils`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from having 2 spyder instances running. When I close both and start only 1, it imports fine.